# Finding velocity at half the maximum amplitude

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I have the question "An oscillator undergoes SHM (simple harmonic motion) with a frequency of 7.2S^-1. If the maximum amplitude is 1.0m, find the velocity at half the maximum amplitude."

Here is my attempt. Is this correct ?

[image]

Comment: I would say - yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your method is correct but you should get $39.178066...$ if you avoid premature rounding off

Comment: You are welcome...