# Factoring the polynomial $3(2x+3)^2 + 7(2x+3) - 6$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

> Factor $3(2x+3)^2 + 7(2x+3) - 6$

**What I did:**

With the substitution $X=2x+3$:
\begin{align}
3(2x+3)^2 + 7(2x+3) - 6
&= 3X^2-9X+2X-6 \\
&= 3X(X-3)+2(X-3) \\
&= (X-3)(3X+2) \\
&=((2x+3)-3)(3(2x+3)+2) \\
&=(2x+0)(6x+9+2) \\
&=(2x)(6x+11)
\end{align}

Comment: You can check this easily at wolframalpha.com. I’d take a look there.

Comment: This is not correct.  If you want us to find the error, you should format it for readability.  The constant term is $24$ while you have $0$

Comment: @Ross Minor nitpick: it's 42, not 24 - you forgot the square

Comment: I think it is readable now

Comment: @Sambo:  actually I forgot the $3$ in front, but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct. You made a sign error:
$$...=(X+3)(3X-2)=...$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1101520)

Comment: @user10354138, I confirmed the correctness of the method and indicated to the OP's mistake. I think the OP can handle the rest. Don't you think so?

Comment: @user10354138 I don't see a problem here.

Comment: @YiFan That comment was generated by review (recommending deletion of answer).  There are two problems with this answer, (1) it is incorrect because the sign error was made earlier than what is indicated here, and (2) this is a comment.  An answer (given what the OP has done) should at least be self-contained.

Comment: @user10354138, 1) you read it as "the error is at this step", while it could be interpreted as "this is what you must get". So it is relative. 2) a comment usually addresses one side/part of the solution and it is not comprehensive. I think here once the OP follows the suggestions given, he can solve the problem completely. 2) by "self-contained" you mean redoing the whole task? I don't think it is recommended on this site, don't you think so?

Comment: @user10354138, also when you edited the OP's question, you changed $x$ to $X$, which is not pedagogical and my answer also suggested this point.

Comment: @bilgamish: no, self-contained doesn't have to do the whole task.  However, it should at least be a (partial) answer.  As for the difference what is the difference between comment and answer, I think [this meta answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20383) and quid's comment on the same page summarised it.

Comment: @user10354128, does OP need the partial answer you are implying, he did all the steps, but got astray with the sign. Now look at this [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069885/finding-velocity-at-half-the-maximum-amplitude/2069939#2069939) and you can find many similar answer on this site which confirm the OP's solution (which is what the OP is after). You could argue for not comment/answer, but hint/answer, maybe.

Comment: OP here - Where did I make the sign error???

Comment: You will see if you open the brackets I wrote and compare with your original expression. Good luck.